# $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$ other than the ones formed by Borel set?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have been reading about probability theory and my textbook talks about how we define probability function on the $\sigma$-algebra on sample space, instead of the sample space $S$ itself.

Then it mentions two examples. First, when $S$ is a countable set, a "natural" choice for $\sigma$-algebra is the power set $2^S$. Then, when $S$ is uncountable (say, $\mathbb{R}$), the $\sigma$-algebra the author mentioned was the one that formed by Borel sets.

My question is, can we use the power set of $\mathbb{R}$ as its $\sigma$-algebra? It seems that $2^\mathbb{R}$ satisfies the three properties of a $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: Yes, the powerset of a set $S$ is always a $\sigma$-algebra on $S$.

Comment: Yes, it's a $\sigma$-algebra, but it turns out that you can't define a measure on it which has all the nice properties we would hope for.  Rather than give up on these nice properties, Lebesgue chose to accept that some subsets of $\mathbb R$ will not be measurable.

Comment: @littleO that is, we cannot prove there is such a measure. There *might* be one, if we believe so. It does imply all sorts of weird things about our set theroretic universe, like that $\mathfrak{c}$ is HUGE.

Comment: One measure on the power set, is a point measure $\mu_p(A) = 1$ iff $p \in A$, otherwise $0$, for every fixed $p$ in the reals.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I think littleO got it right, if one of the nice properties we would hope for is translation invariance. But I'm not sure what Lebesgue thought about that. I've heard that Lebesgue didn't believe in the axiom of choice, so I guess he didn't believe in non-measurable sets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have founded an concrete example here: http://stat.math.uregina.ca/~kozdron/Teaching/Regina/451Fall13/Handouts/451lecture04.pdf